# In isothermal process here the walls of container and piston of conducting walls. Why it is?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Why in isothermal process the wall of container is of conductor instead of insulator ?**

Comment: How else can it exchange heat with the surroundings which is necessary to keep temperature constant?

Answer (score 0):

If the walls were made of insulator matter, the system wouldn't have any way to receive or eject thermal energy, so it probably wouldn't be able to maintain a constant temperature.

More precisely, the first law of thermodynamics would probably look like this:
$$\Delta U=C_v\,\Delta T=W+Q$$

With insulator, $Q=0$ so you can see that $\Delta T$ cannot be zero if the system receives any other form of work.

On the other hand, with conductor, $\Delta T=0$ is possible with $W=-Q$.